# Edmx Entity model inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, edmx

I want to create a generic Entity Model, with some classes and logics above, to put into a DLL and reuse that in various projects. I keep in mind the possibility to extend the generic ModelContainer in another in every project and use the extended ModelContainer to access database. I ask you if it is possible to do so in a "clean way" or I need some work around or "bad stuff".
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand what you want exactly but i think you want to extend the entities generated by `edmx`.

You can do this by using `Partial Classes` or `Extension Methods`.

Comment: I mean if such a thing is provided for visual studio, I noticed that there's no property settable to extend an edmx context, I have to do it from code? and if so, what attributes and other stuff I have to consider to do it? there's no way more "simple" to do that?